# set system date/ constraint

Tags: oracle, ddl

I'm trying to set the default date of the EmpDate column as the current system date. How do I do it in oracle sql? Besides, how do I add multiple column in one command(instead of using two separate ALTER like the code shown below)?

The question is "Add two columns to the EMPLOYEES table. One column, named EmpDate, contains the date of employment for each employee, and its default value should be the system date. The second column, named EndDate, contains employees’ date of termination."

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
Add EmpDate Date;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
Add EndDate Date;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES
  ADD CONSTRAINT empdate
    DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR EmpDate;
```

Comment: DEFAULT SYSDATE

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table Employees add Empdate  date  default sysdate;
alter table Employees add Enddateq  date  ;
```